# installing pip with two versions of python

Tags: software-installation, python, pip

I have a system running an old version of default that did not support pip, I also have Python 2.7.11

I followed the steps [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

but whenever I run the command:

```
python get-pip.py
```

I receive the error

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip
```

How can I resolve this? Thanks

Comment: What is the version of the `python` you actually run? What does "*old version of default*" mean?

Comment: Sorry, meant to say "old version of python"

Comment: Asking again: what version is `python` linked to?

Answer (score 0):

You can install `pip` for Python 2 by running:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```